# Polynomials : Indicate if a is a root non-existent for P(x) then$\frac 1a$is a root

Tags: polynomials

We have $$ P(x)=2x^3+3x^2-3x^1-2 $$

1- Calculate P(-2) & P(1) & P(3) (already answered)

2- Do the Euclidean division for P(x) on $$x +\frac 12$$ (already answered)

3- Indicate if a is a root non-existent for P(x) then$$\frac 1a$$is a root

Conclude the three roots for P(x)

I already answered the two first questions I only want help in the third one

Comment: Hint: $(x+iy)\times\frac{(x-iy)}{(x^2+y^2)}=1$

Comment: Are you concerned with roots of the equation - values for which $P(x)=0$? Which Euclidean division have you done? Possible hint: try computing $x^3P(\frac 1x)$

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: I am not sure what "root non-existent" means. Are you trying to show that if $a\ne0$ is a root, then so is $1/a$? This is true for any [reciprocal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial).